# How to load a map activity in a tab of other activity

Tags: android, google-maps, android-mapview

Hello every one,

In android application  I have a MapActivity called ShowMapActivity. i want to show this map in a tab of another Normal activity called MainActivity.

Note : there are 3 tabs 1st 2 tabs are showing some text data. In the 3rd tab the map should be displayed.

my manifest file of MainActivity is as follows

Please tell me how to accomplish this requirement, or any example resource.

Comment: You seem to have forgotten to include your manifest.

Answer (score 0):

You probably want to specify the content of your map tab using [`TabSpec.setContentView(Intent)`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/TabHost.TabSpec.html#setContent%28android.content.Intent%29), where the Intent refers to ShowMapActivity.